# curve motion of object in Cocos2d

Tags: android, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

i am trying to develop a game. where i have task like that throw a ball from a specific point in curve motion. i have found tutorial http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/ in this object goes in linear motion. can we move an object in curve motion ?

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inside test project there are some examples with curve motion.

UPD: seems like curves not exactly supported, but there's some tricks about it.
Try this

http://dashiellgough.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/cocos2d-move-along-a-curve-bezier-animation

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/4853

Comment: can you share link or any refrence?

Comment: do you actually use cocos2d or cocos2d-x? just cocos2d used for iphone, as i know. So on http://www.cocos2d-x.org inside of pack there are `sample` folder with `TestCpp` project.

Comment: i am following cocos2d.. at your given reference i am finding a source of game that i have given in my question.. is there any sample folder?